# Mostrar en correcto orden datos desde dos foreach en una relacion uno a muchos en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy imprimiendo datos en una tabla desde una relacion uno a muchos por medio de dos foreach

```
 @foreach($pc as $p)
   @foreach($p->Product as $v) 
   <td>{{$v->nombre}}</td>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

el problema es que en las tablas hay esto

Tabla ProductCategory

| id | brands_id | products_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |

Tabla Product

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Televisor |
| 2 | Lampara |
| 3 | Linterna |

Tabla Brand

| id | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Marca 1 |
| 2 | Marca 2 |
| 3 | Marca 3 |

la variable con la consulta trae estos datos:

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "products_id" => 1
    "brands_id" => 1
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null


#attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "products_id" => 2
    "brands_id" => 1
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
```

El problema es que la vista con los Foreach me muestra bien el primer dato al ser las id 1 , pero en el segundo dato que me muestra el id de Product es 2 pero me muestra el nombre del producto 3
¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: El problema es que manejas una relación de muchos a muchos y tú estás definiendo relaciones de Eloquent de uno a muchos

Comment: Está pregunta está relacionada con la anterior?, Las relaciones definidas en la pregunta anterior son las mismas que empleas en el contexto de está?

Comment: si son las mismas relaciones.

Comment: Entonces como te mencioné tienes mal aplicadas las relaciones de Eloquent

Comment: Modifique la relacion, el segundo foreach me devuelve un dato menos y cuando agrego la propiedad de la relacion la aplica en la id del dato de la tabla ProductCategory no mostrandose la categoria correcta

Comment: Si, pero lo que te menciono es que no deberías emplear un `hasMany` sino un `beñlongsToMany`